# How to connect a database using GoDaddy?

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to connect a database to a website. I am using GoDaddy and I am finding it difficult to input the following things in php.

```
$host = "Where do I find this? Is this a number? Do I put the IP Address: Port Number?";
$dbusername = "Does it contain quotes?" Or is it just the username?;
$dbpassword = "Does it contain quotes?" Or is it just the password;
$dbname = "Does it contain quotes?" Or is it just the database name;
// Create connection 
$conn = new mysqli ($host, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);
```

I am assuming the port number is right next to the localhost.

Comment: The other question does not answer this! This question is very specific about the connection part. The other one is entirely different.

Comment: How should we know that? Why not ask your hosting provider?

Comment: @NicoHaase  I was asking how I could figure that out. I wasn't asking you to look them up for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$host =>    Specifies a hostname or an IP address(For example: localhost).

$username => Specifies the MySQL username(For example: my_user).

$password => Specifies the MySQL password(For example: my_password ).

$dbname :  => Specifies the default database to be used(For example: my_db).

All these contain a name with quotes on them.

For example:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
```

Comment: Do you know if I put periods around the $host or include the port? It isn't working right after doing this. Also, do = signs work?

Comment: @W.G. why did you accept this answer if you still have questions?

Comment: Because this person was helping me